# 6V lead battery to 3.6V li ion to add capacity to LED motion light

Tags: batteries, parallel

Is there a way to hook up a 6V lead battery in parallel to a 3.6V li ion battery that powers an LED motion detector light?  Also - it is solar powered.  So ideally it would charge too.

Currently, I have this dinky li ion battery that runs the light.  But it's too dark around Seattle in the winter to get a full charge. I am trying to add some amp hour capacity to the system so the light will work and survive the dark months with minimal charging.

Comment: um, cold temperatures and lead acid batteries, which have a lower capacity per volume than li-ion to begin with? I think you're expecting too much benefit from that. Honestly, the problem is trying to solar power something in the winter; adding a small wind turbine would probably make more sense :D

Comment: Energy out needs to be less than lowest energy in. If not, no amount of batteries are going to work unless you pre-charge a shed full in summer in anticipation of winter or, you get much bigger solar panels.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SEPIC converter to power the LED then use diode to isolate the Li battery and a buck converter which will also be diode isolated, both diodes feed the SEPIC converter with the cathode end to +in. It will stay nice and bright.You will lose a little from the Li battery but the SEPIC converter will boost it for you even as the battery voltage drops over usage. The output voltage of the buck converter will control when the SEPIC converter switches to 6V battery power. Slightly warming the 6V battery when cold will increase its life. You could use a larger battery if you want or even a wall wart. There will be a small drain on the 6V battery when not in use because of the idle current of the SEPIC converter.

Comment: "But it's too dark around Seattle in the winter to get a full charge". No amount of extra electronics, diodes or batteries is going to alter that. The only useful suggestion is using a wall wart but that sort of defeats the object.

Comment: Also note that you must never allow a lead acid battery to be fully depleted in subzero temperatures.  The acid in the battery becomes water and when it freezes, the crystals distort the cell plates, destroying the battery.

Comment: More and bigger solar cells! There is such a thing as worse case design and you ran into it.